# How to detect whether an action is performed everyday in app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am interesting in programming a daily reminder at a specified time set by the user (for example, at 7:20AM every morning), and have the app perform certain functions based on whether the user has completed an action *after* that time or not (for example, if the user completed an action, the app's background will be set to green, otherwise it will be set to red). This will repeat again for the next day at 7:20AM.

I used [this alarm tutorial](http://vimeo.com/29824336) and this [guide](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html) on using repeating notification and so far have figured out how to repeat the notification everyday using `UILocationNotifications`. However, I am stumped on how to detect whether an user action is completed for a particular day. So far the only way I could think of is setting it in a `NSMutableDictionary` that is saved as a `NSUserDefault` and with `{date: completion}` for *every day* of the app use. I was wondering if there is an easier way to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with your planned approach, although if you are going to get a large dataset then perhaps you could use CoreData rather than `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Paulw11 - my reason for not using my approach was that I didn't want to store much data into the phone, but rather have lighter way that could detect the activity day-by-day.

Comment: Well, if you want to know the days on which the app was run. Then you need to store all of the dates, but this is only a few bytes per day, so I wouldn't worry about the storage too much. You could store a single 32 bit int per month and have each bit represent a day, but this is probably more trouble than it is worth.  Another approach is to just store the last time they used the app,  but this won't tell you about missed days.